# Is there a different validation process for "to add Logos for Non-Gmail Accounts"?

Tags: google-schemas, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I received from Google the following instructions to add Logos for Non-Gmail Accounts:

*These instructions explain how to add a logo, or avatar, to a non-Gmail email address, for example mailer@mycompany.com. Once added, all emails from that account will show logos on all three Gmail clients: Android, iOS, Desktop*

1. *In a new incognito window, visit
   https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail*
2. *Create a new account using the non-Gmail email address. You will be
   required to enter a passcode sent to this address, so be sure you
   have access to read this address's email.*
3. *Once you're logged in to the new account, visit
   https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info and click on "Photo" to
   change your profile picture.*
4. *You'll immediately see the new logo on desktop Gmail, including on
   email already sent. Android and iOS clients will take 24 hours to
   start displaying it. You can change the logo whenever you wish, but
   again it will take 24 hours to update on mobile clients.*

I can't follow this instructions because the sender email address of our email marketing communications only exists as a sender for our email marketing tool (SFMC = Salesforce Marketing Cloud). It means that we don't have and inbox associated to it, **so we won't be able to retrieve the passcode mentioned on the step 2 above**.

**NOTE:** I can't configure the domain in order to have an inbox because it will break our email marketing platform configuration.

Is there any other way to validate that I am the owner of the subdomain (instead of receiving a passcode)? Maybe adding some TXT record to the DNS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is the only way to add the sender image in Gmail, since this is the only way to run through the verification.

Can you explain a bit more why adding an inbox would break your Marketing Cloud configuration?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ymar. The filezone provided by SMFC to be configured in our subdomain's DNS includes a MX record pointing to Salesforce servers (exacttarget.com). It means that Salesforce would be the responsible of creating and managing any inbox associated to the subdomain. So, I've asked their Support Team and they have confirmed me that "there is no way that a sender email address of your subdomain could have an active mail box, neither redirect emails sent to an email address of the subdomain to an external mail box".

Comment: There should be a way to add the logo by adding DNS records. The support has been announced last year and is called 'the BIMI standard'. You can find more information in this article: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/gsuite-security-updates-for-gmail-meet-chat-and-admin

In the article there is a link to a guide to implement it: https://bimigroup.org/implementation-guide/. There is also a DMARC record checker in order to check if the record has been set up correctly.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you again, @Ymar. I know about BIMI and we are working on implementing it but, as you may know, BIMI is still in pilot phase and I'd need to get the logo working on Gmail clients (Android, iOS, Desktop) in a short-term. Copying from bimigroup's site: "Currently, BIMI is only live in production at Yahoo! and is available for viewing in both the webmail and the Yahoo! Mobile application. Google is currently running a closed pilot with a small set of pre-determined participants.". So, I'd need a confirmation from Google if there is a different verification process to the procedure above.

Comment: @ENRICAD Ah missed that, let's hope that Google starts rolling out BIMI support soon.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative your alternative is to use BIMI record, it`s valid for the many of ESP including Gmail: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-marketing/bimi/

Comment: Yup, except you have to pay $1500 for the certificate, just to show your logo in emails. Even then there’s no guarantee it will work. Feels like a scam… Official by big companies, but scam.